# install4j windows service -- restart on failure option

Tags: install4j

I have a working install4j 6.1.3 service. Due to a 3rd party memory leak we want to be able to have our application exit and then have the service automatically restart itself on a regular basis. There is a checkbox on the install4j create services option screen "Restart on Failure" that says that it should restart the service unless the exit code is '0'.

The java application is calling System.exit(27).
We have also tried codes -1, 0 and 1.
The application exits, but the windows service does not auto restart.

Is there something more that needs to be configured for this to work, or a different way to exit the java application to get the service to automatically restart itself?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the recovery tab of your service in the Windows service manager?

Comment: Looking at that tab helped us resolve the issue. Turns out that one of the developers who was working on this is not on the corporate network and the installer was specifying a user account to run the service. That account didn't exist on his computer. There is an error that the service creation had an issue, but it appeared that the service did install(and did run). We were going to look into what that was after solving the issue at hand. 
It looks like that if the user account isn't available that the service creation doesn't continue on to turn on the features on the recovery tab.

Comment: Simply changing the user account in the installer to be local user and then running the installer to recreate the service allow the recovery tab options to be set. Once they were the feature of restarting on failure worked as I expected it to.
Thank you for your help!